# C++ - Template Class -> Static function -> Link error for static function pointer

Tags: c++, linux, templates, function-pointers

**Bellow code is successfully compiling at Visual studio & Solaris compiler. But getting the link error at g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.3.4. Please let me know how to fix this link error at linux? 
*Note:* To make code simple and cleaner I have typed proxy code here.**

//----------------  **a1.h** -----------

```
#ifndef __a1_h__
#define __a1_h__

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

namespace ServiceManagement
{
    template <typename T>
    class ClassA1
    {
    public:
        ClassA1() {}

        typedef std::auto_ptr<T>(*addFunc)(int, int);
        static void setAddFunc(addFunc f)
        {
            s_AddFunc = f;
        }

    private:
        static addFunc s_AddFunc;
    };
}

#endif
```

//----------------  **b1.h** -----------

```
#ifndef __b11_h__
#define __b11_h__

#include "a1.h"

typedef ServiceManagement::ClassA1<int> setPosType;

namespace ServiceManagement
{
    class ClassB1
    {
    public:
        ClassB1() {}

        static void Register();
    private:
        std::auto_ptr<setPosType> m_ptrMsg;
    };

}

#endif
```

//----------------  b1.cpp -----------

```
#include "b1.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//setPosType::addFunc setPosType::s_AddFunc;
template <> setPosType::addFunc setPosType::s_AddFunc;

namespace AA
{
    namespace v2
    {
        std::auto_ptr<int> message2_(int a, int b)
        {
            int c = a + b;

            std::auto_ptr<int> p1(new int);
            *p1.get() = c;

            return p1;
        }
    }
}

namespace ServiceManagement
{

    void ClassB1::Register()
    {
        setPosType::addFunc f1 = ::AA::v2::message2_;

        setPosType::setAddFunc(f1);
    }
}

int main()
{

    int  i = 0;
    cin >> i;
    return 0;
}
```

**Link Error:**
/usr/bin/c++    -pthread  -g -w -W -Wall -Wno-long-long -g -ldl -lm -lnsl -m64 -o -pthread -std=gnu++0x    -Bdynamic

.. build  " CMakeFiles/templateTest.dir/b1.cpp.o  -o ../../../../../..//templateTest -rdynamic
CMakeFiles/templateTest.dir/**b1.cpp.o:** In function `**ServiceManagement::ClassA1<int>::setAddFunc(std::auto_ptr<int> (*)(int, int))'**:
/templateTest/**a1.h:18: undefined reference to`ServiceManagement::ClassA1::s_AddFunc'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**

**Note 2**:
already static variable is defined at b1.cpp like below, 
**template <> setPosType::addFunc setPosType::s_AddFunc;**

Comment: Your question's formatting is mangled quite a bit, I can't make head or tail of the error log. Could you edit it and use backquotes (```) for inline code and `<pre></pre>` for the (html-escaped) output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) It works once you initialize the member variable:

```
template <> setPosType::addFunc setPosType::s_AddFunc = 0;
```

Obviously, without the initializer, this line is a declaration rather than a definition, but, honestly, I do not see why.

2.) Clang tells me that defining the static member outside its namespace is a C++11 extension. Better use

```
namespace ServiceManagement {
   template <> setPosType::addFunc setPosType::s_AddFunc = 0;
}
```

Comment: I have used this code, but still getting the same link error.

Comment: I've tried it now. It works once you initialize the member variable: `template <> setPosType::addFunc setPosType::s_AddFunc = 0;` I'll update my answer.